# Looking for a solution to create a landing page and automatically replicate it x number of times - each with a different footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, merge

I have a series projects where in each project I may need to create up to 63 identical landing pages in up to 23 different languages. The content in the footer is often the identical but localized for the country/language/google analytics onclick tracking. Is there a tool where I may be able to quickly build the site, and almost "mail merge" the footer into place based upon locale/country/language?

Comment: If you control the serving of the content, you should be able to do some sort of "server side include" depending on your environment.

Comment: inject content serverside based on locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't comfortable setting up a local server / programming with a server side language (php, ruby, etc), then use a client-side framework such as ember (http://emberjs.com/about/). It will enable you to set the header and footer once, and create the additional landing pages with only the content they uniquely require.